# Mongoose: find and select only the fields specified in a virtual

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a `UserSchema` schema in mongoose:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  role: {type: String, default: 'user'},
  following: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  followers: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  facebook: {},
  twitter: {},
  github: {},
  google: {}
});
```

I've created a virtual `profile` which returns only the information for the public profile:

```
UserSchema
  .virtual('profile')
  .get(function() {
    return {
      'username': this.username,
      'name': this.name,
      'role': this.role
    };
  });
```

My problem is how to get only this information when I'm making a `find` request. Here's my code:

```
UserSchema.statics = {
  list: function (options, callback) {
    var criteria = options.criteria || {};

    this.find(criteria)
      .select(/* What to put here? */)
      .limit(options.perPage)
      .skip(options.perPage * options.page)
      .exec(callback);
  } 
};
```

Of course, I can simply put there `username`, `name` and `role` but in that case I'd have code repetition. Can I avoid that?

Comment: Don't have a Node.js/Mongo shell to try now, but I think if you just select('profile'), it would work.
What do you mean by code repetition? That you'd have to change this in two places if you ever change your virtual?

Comment: No, unfortunately that returns only the _id field. And yes, I don't want to change same thing in two (or in future more than two) places in case that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In populate Try it:

```
UserSchema.virtual('profile', {
  ref: 'Job',
  localField: 'job_id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
  options: {
    select: 'name type'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to mongooejs document

> Only non-virtual properties work as part of queries and for field selection.

You can do like this

```
exports.show = function (req, res, next) {
  var userId = req.params.id;

  User.findById(userId, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.json(user.profile);
  });
};
```

But not this

```
exports.devs = function (req, res, next) {
  User.find({role: 'developer'}, 'developer_profile', function (err, users) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
  res.status(200).json(users);
  });
};
```

You can read more in here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the virtual `profile` for any reason other than this `find`? Your virtual really just specifies a number of fields, nothing more dynamic, so if you are just trying to select fields in the query I would stick with that (`.select('username name role')`). If you want to make it reusable… just make the string a value in a module you can inject via `require`. Then you can change it wherever you need to, and use it like `select(profileFields)`.